# Workbox - Service worker index.html/asset mismatch

Tags: service-worker, workbox

I have a simple service worker set up with [workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/). The precache contains `index.html` and a `main.xxx.js` javascript bundle (among other things) where xxx is updated on each build. The precache setup is very simple, using [workbox-build](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/precache-files/workbox-build).

```
workboxBuild.injectManifest({
  // ...
  globPatterns: [
    'index.html',
    'main.*.js',
    // ...
  ]
})
```

The problem that I'm seeing randomly (particularly in Safary and Firefox) is that the index seems to get into a bad (outdated) state where it references `main.xxx.js` yet the current build is on `main.yyy.js`, which doesn't exist and breaks the site. I can verify this by visiting Chrome which shows the correct reference to `main.yyy.js` in the `index.html` and works fine. What am I missing here and what strategy can I use to insure that I always have the same version?

To be clear, nothing seems to solve the problem once it's in a bad state. Refreshing does nothing.

Comment: review your build and the SW lifecycle around INSTALL/ACTIVATE. 
If you are using WB.generateSW in each build then the precache.manifest will change to .yyy version.  Then, using devtools verify that you are forcing install/activate with each request on 'index'  .  Follow those steps with manifest and install/activate and u should get better result

Comment: PS.. less frequently, there may be some situations where you have to explicitly del the cache using devtools. But that would indicate a logical flow  with a flaw in your builds collaboration with the actual SW install

Comment: if ur still have issues then reivew your 'watchify' steps re: events that recreate the problem bundle... NOTE every time watch -> bundle.yyy , YOU MUST account for the new version in the build.task responsible for WB.generateSW().  be careful here

Comment: @RobertRowntree thanks for the tips. I'm not using wb.generateSW, and I'm not dong anything explicitly on install/activate but will look into it. mostly just registering routes in sw.js

Comment: I think the build process is solid, it's an angular project so the cli handles it, don't see any problems

Comment: Are you calling `workbox.skipWaiting()` in your `swSrc` file, by any chance? If so, then the following would explain the mismatch: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/lifecycle#skip_the_waiting_phase